# select column and If value exist show a column and show yes or no

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to write a query to add extra column (ACCESS) if the data in ACCESS_TPE o existed then show "yes" otherwise show "no.

Table

```
EMPLID  RCD DI_ACCESS_NAME  ACCESS
123450  0   TK              Y
123450  1   HCS-P           Y
123450  1   SI              Y
123450  3   NATO            Y
123451  0                   N
123451  1                   N
123452  0   HCS-P           Y
123453  0                   N
```

My query is

```
SELECT emplid, empl_rcd, di_access_name, (CASE WHEN coalesce(di_access_name,'') <> '' THEN 'yes' else 'no' end) as access FROM PS_DI_SEC_ACCESS;
```

or

```
SELECT emplid, empl_rcd, di_access_name,(CASE WHEN di_access_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' else 'no' end) as access
FROM PS_DI_SEC_ACCESS;
```

both gives me error,
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 116

Comment: ACCESS is an [Oracle SQL Reserved Word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html). You must use a different column alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACCESS` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html) and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier. Either use a different word or a quoted identifier.

```sql
SELECT emplid,
       empl_rcd,
       di_access_name,
       CASE WHEN di_access_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' else 'no' end as "ACCESS"
FROM   PS_DI_SEC_ACCESS;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT emplid,
       empl_rcd,
       di_access_name,
       NVL2(di_access_name, 'yes', 'no') as "ACCESS"
FROM   PS_DI_SEC_ACCESS;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W5wuYMCQ)

*Note: In Oracle, `''` and `NULL` are identical and Oracle uses tri-nary logic where `NULL <> anything` gives the result `NULL` rather than true so your first query will not work.*